# Javascript function-call requiring unique name

Tags: javascript, php

Currently have a text "button" in my `View` that calls a Javascript function by its `id`.

The `View` code with a mix of PHP and HTML and a little JS.

```
<?php foreach($restaurant_by_legal_entities[$legal_entity_id] as $restaurant_id): ?>
    <tr style="outline: thin solid">
        <td class="left">
            <a
                id="collapse-restaurant"
                data-token="<?= $token ?>"
                style="text-decoration:none"
                class="text"><?= $text_expand_symbol ?>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"><strong>Sub-total - <?= $restaurant_name ?></</td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="right"><strong>￥<?= $total_by_restaurants[$restaurant_id] ?></strong></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

My JS file:

```
/**
 * Generate the URL to collapse the financial report to only show the totals
 * only city, legal entity, and restaurant
 */
function collapse() {
    console.log("Blah");
    var url = commonGet('report/sale_financial', $(this).data('token'));

    var collapse = $('input[name=\'collapse\']').attr('value');

    if (collapse == 1) {
        url += '&collapse=' + 0;
    } else if (collapse == 0){
        url += '&collapse=' + 1;
    }

    window.location = url;
}

$('#collapse-restaurant').click(collapse);
```

I noticed that when I click the first button (first meaning the first index), my `collapse` function would be called [tested using the Chrome debugger]. However, everything after the first index would not be called. After a little self-research, it appears that each `id` must be unique, and currently, it is not.

Since it appears that the `id` must be unique per `.click()`, how do I get around this issue?

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Use a class, not ID.

Comment: And if you want to get the current value of an input, you have to use `.val()`, not `.attr('value')`. The latter will just get the value from the HTML, not what the user has entered.

Comment: Hello @Barmar. Do you mean replacing the `class=text`with `class=collapse-restaurant`? I tried that, but it appears I am missing the button now.

Comment: `class="text collapse-restaurant"`

Comment: @Barmar I have changed everything to `class="text ...", thanks! However, according to my debugger, the function never gets called, making me think I may need to change something in my JS file?

Comment: Did you change the handler binding to `$(".collapse-restaurant")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a `class` instead of `id` in my View:

```
<?php foreach($restaurant_by_legal_entities[$legal_entity_id] as $restaurant_id): ?>
    <tr style="outline: thin solid">
        <td class="left">
            <a
                class="text collapse-restaurant"
                data-token="<?= $token ?>"
                style="text-decoration:none"><?= $text_expand_symbol ?>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"><strong>Sub-total - <?= $restaurant_name ?></</td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="left"></td>
        <td class="right"><strong>￥<?= $total_by_restaurants[$restaurant_id] ?></strong></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Changed the handler binding to this in the JS file:

```
$('.collapse-restaurant').click(collapse);
```